# varchar(max) equivilent in MySQL for T-SQL varchar(max) comparison

Tags: mysql, t-sql, text, varchar, linked-server

i have the following where clause

```
WHERE
(
    target.sender_name <> source.sender_name
)
```

target aliases a table in Microsoft SQL Server while source aliases an almost identical table on a MySQL Server linked via a Linked Server

Originally i had sender_name in both tables as a text field, trying to keep the 2 tables incidental, however the query that the above clause was when, when i tried to run it spat out

```
The data types text and text are incompatible in the not equal to operator.
```

doing a bit of looking around i learned that text in tsql was depreciated and i should be using varchar(max), doing so however outputted this error

```
The data types varchar(max) and text are incompatible in the not equal to operator.
```

looking around it seems that an equivalent is `VARCHAR(65535)` however using that would cause problems in a table which has **4 text fields** and the error i'm getting i believe would just be the same for the other 3 fields that i have in the same clause

so i am wondering if there is an equivalent to `varchar(max)` in mysql which i can use in my clause with a `varchar(max)` field in tsql

NOTE: the query that the clause is in runs in tsql, it's just the table on the linked server which is MySQL

EDIT: what the clause goes into is an UPDATE query, it checks every field and updates record in which any of the data is different, it's only ever used to sync up the 2 tables so that i can localize the work on the servers rather than using a linked server to do stuff like INNER JOINS

Comment: MySQL does not have an exact equivalent of varchar(max).

Comment: Create a temp table on the MSSQL server select the data over from MySQL and then use the local temp table to work with on the MSSQL server machine.

Comment: @Namphibian actually the tables are in a sense are temp tables, all MSSQL work goes on it's local table and after all that work is done i update any records in the MySQL Table which may be different then finish off the work on the MySQL Server, this why i'm not doing INNER JOINS across the linked server. have updated by question with this information